# Select just first a href in element jquery

Tags: jquery, find

I have tried to find similar question, but generally all have been diferrent
This is what i need

**HTML**

```
<div class="items">
   <div class="box">
        <label class="input">
            <span class="icon"></span>
            <input type="text" class="input" required />
            <a class="btn-no-borders">
                <i class="delete"></i>
            </a>
        </label>

        <label class="input">
            <span class="icon"></span>
            <input type="text" class="input" required />
            <a class="btn-no-borders">
                <i class="delete"></i>
            </a>
        </label>

        <label class="input">
            <span class="icon"></span>
            <input type="text" class="input" required />
            <a class="btn-no-borders">
                <i class="delete"></i>
            </a>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

What i need is that i only select first A,and not all others
here is my code so far

```
$('.items').find('a').attr('data-first', '1').addClass('hidden');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:eq(0)` or `:first` selector

```
 $('.items a:eq(0)').attr('data-first', '1').addClass('hidden');
```

or

```
 $('.items a:first').attr('data-first', '1').addClass('hidden');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$('.items').find('a').first().attr('data-first', '1').addClass('hidden');
```